# what can i do to improve performance of this code

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code that looks though all Contacts and does a count on each email that's been sent to them and if they haven't open/click the last X amount then return them in a list

at the moment the code is taking about 10 mins to run, is there anything I can do to improve this?

I know I could limit the amount returned but that's still slow.

```
var contactList =
        (from c in db.Contacts
            where c.Accounts_CustomerID == Account.AccountID && !c.Deleted && !c.EmailOptOut
            select c).ToList();

    foreach (var person in contactList)
    {
        var SentEmails =
            (from c in db.Comms_Emails_EmailsSents where c.ContactID == person.ID select c).OrderBy(
                x => x.DateSent).Take(Last).ToList();

        if (SentEmails.Count == Last)
        {
            if (!Clicks)
            {
                if (SentEmails.Count(x => x.Opens == 0) == Last)
                {
                    ReturnContacts.Add(person);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (SentEmails.Count(x => x.Clicks == 0) == Last)
                {
                    ReturnContacts.Add(person);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ReturnContacts;
```

Comment: Take a performance-profiler (e.g. dotTrace) first to enlighten WHAT exactly goes slowly.

Comment: You need a Join query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .ToList()'s and use IQueryables. By using iqueryables the code will execute once and reduces memory. The ToList() retrieves all entities and store them in memory, which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Run the logic on the db - rewrite a query using joins etc., so that it returns a result set that already contains relevant data.

What you're doing now is performing a db query for each initial query result. That can mean A LOT of queries.

If you offload that to the RDBMS you can always try and and optimize it there (by introducing indexes etc.).

EDIT: I rewrote the code in notepad:

```
foreach(var record in (from c in db.Contacts
join es in db.Comms_Emails_EmailsSents
on c.Id equals es.ContactId
where c.Accounts_CustomerID == Account.AccountID && !c.Deleted && !c.EmailOptOut
orderby c.Id, es.DateSent descending
select new {opens=es.Opens, clicks=es.Clicks, person=c})
.GroupBy(r=>r.person)){
    var mails = record.Take(Last).ToList();
    if(mails.Count == Last){
        if(!Clicks){
            if(mails.Count(x=>x.opens == 0) == Last){
                 ReturnContacts.Add(record.Key);
            }
        }
    }else
            {
                if (SentEmails.Count(x => x.Clicks == 0) == Last)
                {
                    ReturnContacts.Add(record.Key);
                }
            }

}
```

I don't have time at hand to mock up a db and test it. Also, this approach performs a join between contacts and emails, and if you have 100k emails per person, this might be a very bad idea. You could optimize it by using rank function, but I'd say that if performance is still bad, you could start thinking of doing db-side optimizations, as this data structure is - at least to my, non-dba eyes - not perfectly suited for this kind of querying.

Comment: what would be the best way do write this in sql? using cursors?

Comment: Exactly NOT using cursors... if possible ;) I'll look at the code and try to update my answer.